# if i declare 5 values in 25 size of an array, how can i find used size of the array in VB Script?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

```
dim a(100)
a(0)=9,a(1)=3,a(2)=-3,a(3)=8,a(4)=2
```

how can i find size of used array(i.e used size is 5

Answer (score 2):

You have to count the non-empty elements:

```
Option Explicit

Function UsedElms(a)
  UsedElms = 0
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      If Not IsEmpty(a(i)) Then UsedElms = UsedElms + 1
  Next
End Function

Dim a(5)
a(2) = 2
a(4) = 4
WScript.Echo "ub:", UBound(a), "sz:", UBound(a) + 1, "us:", UsedElms(a)
```

output:

```
cscript 23027576.vbs
ub: 5 sz: 6 us: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky one-liner that I just thought of. It essentially counts the number of empty elements by converting them to spaces and then trimming them off.

```
intLastIndex = UBound(a) - Len(Join(a, " ")) + Len(Trim(Join(a, " ")))
```

Just for fun! Don't go putting it into your production code. It would certainly be more efficient as a two-liner:

```
s = Join(a, " ")
intLastIndex = UBound(a) - Len(s) + Len(Trim(s))
```

Ekkehard has the proper answer here, though. This hack only works if your array is filled contiguously.